# unexpected token inside variable value

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm trying to use an array in my front end js but trying to use the value with !{} and #{} gives me a syntax error inside the variable. I've tried to json stringify and parse but got no results. here is the code

```
 var arrayData =("!{adverts}");
```

and here is what I get

```
var arrayData =JSON.parse("{ _id: random_String,
updatedAt: 2017-03-02T20:39:35.023Z,
createdAt: 2017-03-02T20:39:35.023Z,
identifier: 'random_string'}");
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels really sloppy but I was able to solve it by creating a variable in my pug, stringifying it there, and then referencing that variable in my js.

in pug:

```
  - var stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(adverts);
```

in js:

```
    var data = !{stringifiedData};
```

Comment: You can also do `var data = !{JSON.stringify(adverts)};`. That creates a JSON-ified output of `adverts`, in the form of your `data` variable.